# Turn different types of missing values into pandas-recognisable NA's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains a variety of different values that indicate missingness. I modified it in a way that now they should be all specified as 'NaN' like this:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', '-', 'jack'],
        'Age':['20', '0', '19', ''],
       'color':['yellow','Na','blue','red']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def missing_values(x):
    
    missingness_indicators = ["NaN","NAN","NA","Na","n/a", "na", "--","-"," ", "-inf", "inf", "nan", "None", "0", "", np.nan] 
    
    modified_df = df.replace(missingness_indicators,'NaN')

    modified_df["color"] = modified_df.loc[:,'color'].fillna(method='bfill', axis=0) #LOCF
    
    return modified_df
```

But using pandas functions that build on the recognized missing values does not work, i think this is due to the fact that I did not import the dataframe with those values specified (as this would have led to other problems, I'm working on a bigger dataset than the example)
I am looking now for a way to apply pandas functions like `.fillna` on this dataset.

Comment: if you are reading a file you can use the [`na_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter to define your custom NaN values

Comment: I know this but my input in what i'm working on is already a pandas dataframe so i am looking for a different solution

Comment: you might be replacing with the string 'NaN', try using None (no quotes) or np.nan instead

Answer (score 0):

Use np.nan to replace the 'indicators':

```
modified_df = df.replace(missingness_indicators,'NaN')
```

with

```
modified_df = df.replace(missingness_indicators, np.nan)
```